# Laravel 9 Get 2 pivots or tables and display jobs for a logged in user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, pivot

I'm trying to display a list of JOBS for VEHICLES only if the USER is part of that DEPARTMENT and the VEHICLE is in a certain STOCK level.

```
USER TABLE
ID

DEPARTMENT TABLE
ID

DEPARTMENT_USER is a pivot
ID USER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID

JOBS
ID DEPARTMENT_ID VEHICLE_ID
```

I have no problem displaying each job for a logged in user if they are assigned to that department using this code

```
public function jobs_active()
{
return $this->hasManyThrough(Job::class, DepartmentUser::class, 'user_id', 'department_id', 'id', 'department_id');
}
```

Now I would like to only show the jobs if a vehicle is in certain stock group and where the user has access to that department

```
VEHICLE
ID STOCK_ID

STOCKS
ID DEPARTMENT_IDS
```

Might not be clear but any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit more Eloquent to do this with relationships on models, but given the table structure you've provided, you can do this with a `DB`     query.

```php
function userJobs($userId) {
    return DB::table("JOBS")
    ->selectRaw("JOBS.*")
    ->leftJoin("VEHICLE", "VEHICLE.ID", "=", "JOBS.VEHICLE_ID");
    ->leftJoin("STOCKS", "STOCKS.ID", "=", "VEHICLE.STOCK_ID");
    ->leftJoin("DEPARTMENT_USER", "DEPARTMENT_USER.DEPARTMENT_ID", "=", "STOCKS.DEPARTMENT_IDS")
    ->where("DEPARTMENT_USER.USER_ID", $userId);
}
```